# CKFinder - Quick Upload not passing URL to image Info tab after successful upload

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

When I use the "Quick Upload" tab to upload a file, the URL is not passed to the "Image Info" tab after a successful upload. If I select OK from the "Quick Upload" after a successful upload, CKFinder switches to the "Image Info" tab, and the following error message "Image source URL is missing" appears. Can anyone shed light on why this might be occurring?

Comment: Are you using CKFinder or your own uploader?

Comment: I am using CKFinder's uploader

Comment: Then you should ask their support team, it doesn't seem that SO is the correct place for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

In CKEditor config -

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/VirtualDirectoryName/ControllerName/ActionName";
```

Your Action Method

```
public class ControllerName: Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ActionName(HttpPostedFileBase upload, string CKEditorFuncNum, string CKEditor, string langCode)
        {
            if (upload != null)
            {
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);

                string basePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
                upload.SaveAs(basePath + "\\" + fileName);

                string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath + "/Uploads/" + fileName;

                HttpContext.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + url + "\");</script>");
                HttpContext.Response.End();
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It work for me with CKEditor 4. You can try like this:

```
public ActionResult uploadnow(HttpPostedFileWrapper upload, string CKEditorFuncNum)
    {
        string path = "";
        string pathWeb ="";
        if (upload != null)
        {
            string ImageName = upload.FileName;
            string extention = Path.GetExtension(ImageName);
            string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmmssms");
            ImageName = name + extention;
            pathWeb = "/images/uploads/" + ImageName;
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/uploads"), ImageName);
            upload.SaveAs(path);
            HttpContext.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + pathWeb + "\");</script>");
            HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
        return View();
    }
```